# Merging and moving folders in loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, file-io, directory, whitespace

I have a large library of music files stored as `./"Artist Name"/"Album Name"/"audio files"`.

I would like to re-organize to `./"Artist name --- Album name"/"audio files"`

And be able to put it back to how it was.

Comment: `i've tried` so what you tried? can you post your progress.

Answer (score 0):

This is your first loop

```
    mkdir "ArtistName-Albumname"
    cd "ArtistName/Albumname"
    for filename in *; do
         mv "$filename" "$ArtistName-Albumname/" ;;
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script to merge folder from `"Artist Name"/"Album Name"` to `"Artist name - Album name"`

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

cd /PATH

find . -type f |while read -r line
do
   file=${line##*/}
   folder=${line%/*}
   album=${folder##*/}
   folder=${folder%/*}
   artist=${folder##*/}
   newfolder="$artist - $album"
   mkdir -p "$newfolder"
   echo mv "$line" "$newfolder"
done
```

If you understand above script, you should be fine to write a reverse one.

Comment: Thanks! This one does the mkdir for each audio file. It is possibly better off only iterating for each album, renaming and moving the whole folder, ignoring what's inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will get you started. It doesn't do anything but just parses your structure and works out what needs doing:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -depth 2 -type d | while IFS= read p
do
   p=${p:2}     # Trim ./ from start
   album=${p##*/}   # album is everything after /
   artist=${p%/*}   # artist is everything before /
   newloc="${artist} - ${album}"
   echo Would move $artist/$album to ${newloc}
done
```

Sample output:

```
Would move artist1/album1 to artist1 - album1
Would move artist1/album2 to artist1 - album2
Would move artist1/album3 to artist1 - album3
Would move artist1/album4 to artist1 - album4
Would move artist2/album1 to artist2 - album1
Would move artist2/album2 to artist2 - album2
Would move artist2/album3 to artist2 - album3
Would move artist3/album1 to artist3 - album1
Would move artist3/album2 to artist3 - album2  
Would move artist3/album3 to artist3 - album3
Would move artist4/album1 to artist4 - album1
Would move artist4/album2 to artist4 - album2
Would move artist4/album3 to artist4 - album3
Would move artist4/album4 to artist4 - album4
Would move artist4/album5 to artist4 - album5
```

The reverse operation is tricky as there may be a hyphen naturally occurring in an album name, so it will be hard to differentiate that from the hyphen introduced by the code below.

Comment: Thanks! I can use something that never occurs instead of the hyphen. I am the only one seeing it anyway. 

But I get error "find: paths must precede expression: 2" executing this. Any clue?

Comment: In order to debug, add " -xv" to end of first line. Also, did you copy the dot after the word "find"?

Comment: The dot was there, yes.

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to maintain linebreaks here
`code`#!/bin/bash -xv
find . -depth 2 -type d | while IFS= read p
do
   p=${p:2}     # Trim ./ from start
   album=${p##*/}   # album is everything after /
   artist=${p%/*}   # artist is everything before /
   newloc="${artist} - ${album}"
   echo Would move $artist/$album to ${newloc}
done
+ find . -depth 2 -type d
+ IFS=
+ read p
find: paths must precede expression: 2
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]`code`

Comment: Mmm.. weird. I don't know what's up with your "find". What platform are you on? Are you using /bin/find, or do you have something else in your path? Try typing "which find". Also try supplying the full path to /bin/find inside the script.

Comment: Sorry. Run it on cygwin, w7... /usr/bin/find... find (GNU findutils) 4.5.9
Packaged by Cygwin (4.5.9-2)

Answer (score 0):

Took some time for an amateur. But here's my final sollution. Thank you so much for your input @mark @BMW.

```
function flatten() {
echo flattening...
    ls -ld --format=single-column */* | while IFS= read albumpath
        do
            echo Flattening "$albumpath"
            artist=${albumpath%/*}   # artist is everything before /
            echo Artist: "$artist"
            echo Album: "$albumpath"
            album=${albumpath##*/} # album is everything after  /
            newfolder="$artist --- $album"
            echo Moving "$albumpath" to "$newfolder"
            mv "$albumpath" "$newfolder"
        done
    find . -depth -type d -empty -delete #delete all empty (artist)folders

}

function unflatten() {
ls -ld --format=single-column */ | while IFS= read pathname
do

    echo REVERSING "$pathname" ;    
    artist=${pathname% ---*}   # artist is everything before " ---"
    echo Artist: "$artist"
    if [ ! -d "$artist" ]; 
        then
            echo Creating "$artist" folder 
            mkdir "$artist"
    fi

    album=${pathname##*--- }   # album is everything after "--- "   
    album=${album%/*}   # strip trailing /
    echo Album: "$album"
    echo Moving "$pathname" "$artist"/"$album"
    mv "$pathname" "$artist"/"$album"
done
```

}